# Should I be able to add the same top post to my "developer story" multiple times?

Tags: bug, developer-story, top-post

IMHO it doesn't really make sense to have the same "top" post in one's developer story multiple times. Still, the system currently allows this, which I guess isn't intended. (If that was the intention so far, feel free to change this from [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).)

### To reproduce:

1. Go to [your developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current) page on Stack Overflow Jobs.
2. In the "Add a new item" box, click "Top post"
3. Paste the "share" URL of one of your posts into the "paste a link" input field
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 (with the same URL)

#### Expected:

Subsequent additions of the same post are either silently ignored or some message is displayed that the post was already part of the developer story. In either case, the post isn't shown in the story multiple times.

#### Observed:

A new entry for the post is added to the story for each repetition. These persist when reloading the page, but can individually be deleted again by clicking through their respective cog-icon menu.

Comment: I don't see a real problem here. The developer story is just like a CV imo. You can also add the same function/achievement there multiple times, and it will likely scare away future employers if you do.

Comment: Sure, but same function/achievement is something the system can't possibly detect, unless they've exactly the same content. Otherwise it could be two actually different functions/achievements with very similar description. Top posts in contrast would be trivial to de-duplicate.

Comment: @ErikA I once heard (but now cannot find a source for) that computerized grading of essay questions once gave full marks to, "Monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey." Surely SO can do better.

Comment: @Draco18s Hey, where did you find a copy of my essay? That was supposed to be private! I poured my soul into that essay!

Comment: @Draco18s How do you think I got my name? That grading program was gold!

Comment: @HereticMonkey enough to get you to turn away from religious dogma? Do you now worship it or something?

Comment: @ErikA was it an essay about ook?